# Reduce multi value to a single one

Tags: grafana

I'm using Grafana Grafana v7.0.6
So the situation is:
i've to monitor CPU load on 20+ servers. i've a metric node_cpu_seconds_total and it returns all each core separately, so in looks like:
server1_core0, server1_core1 and so on.
The question:
is it possible to sum cores and to have single value for each server and not for each core?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
sum by (instance) (node_cpu_seconds_total)
```

Comment: Thank U, that worked, but not as i expected. I made:
sum by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="host1", mode!="idle"}[5m]))
and it gave me back 114%. That seems i did something wrong, though i've excluded idle.

Comment: It's expected to get a value bigger than 100% because you have more than one CPU. Use "sum by (cpu, instance)" to see the value for each CPU. Note: use "irate" instead of "rate".